# Custom post types not yet registered in Widgets_init?

Tags: php, oop, wordpress

I made a plugin that creates custom post types and widgets with those custom post types. The custom post type is registered with the `init` action tag and the widget with the `widget_init`.

Like so:

```
public function __construct() {
    // load the modules
    add_action( 'init', array($this, 'addModule') );

}

public function addModule() {
    // register the post type.
    register_post_type( $this->post_type, $this->getArgs() );
}
```

And the widget is called like this:

```
add_action('widgets_init', function() {
    register_widget('Webburo\Widgets\project\ProjectsWidget'); 
});
```

When I `var_dump()` the post types with `get_post_types()` in the widget code, it won't show the newly registered post types. So it seems to me that the post types are not yet registered in the `widget_init`. Is there something I'm doing wrong or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently the `widget_init` is fired at priority 1 of the `init` action. That explains why my post types weren't yet registered. I've set my action to priority 0 so my post types will be registered before my widgets will.

```
add_action( 'init', array($this, 'addModule'), 0, 1);
```

Source: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have set the public key in the arguments passed in the `register_post_type()` function.

Then use the below code to get all the public registered post type :

```
$args = array(
   'public'   => true,
);

$output = 'names'; // names or objects, note names is the default
$operator = 'and'; // 'and' or 'or'

$post_types = get_post_types( $args, $output, $operator ); 

foreach ( $post_types  as $post_type ) {    
   echo '<p>' . $post_type . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: I've set the public key true, but still don't get the custom post types i've registered. However if I for example use the function in an `admin_init` action, I can see the custom post types. It's like it isn't registered yet at the moment of the widget code.

Comment: That might be the reason, since the admin_init is triggered before any other hook when a user accesses the admin area. 
and init hook is loaded and followed by others , that is widget hook and etc